# One-hot encoding of categories

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I have a list like similar to this:

```
list = ['Opinion, Journal, Editorial',
        'Opinion, Magazine, Evidence-based',
        'Evidence-based']
```

where the commas split between categories eg. Opinion and Journal are two separate categories. The real list is much larger and has more possible categories. I would like to use one-hot encoding to transform the list so that it can be used for machine learning. For example, from that list I would like to produce a sparse matrix containing data like:

```
list = [[1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

Ideally, I would like to use [scikit-learn's one hot encoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) as I presume this would be the most efficient.

In response to [@nbrayns](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4681732/nbryans) comment:

The idea is to transform the list of categories from text to a vector wherby if it belongs to that category it will be assigned 1, otherwise 0. For the above example, the headings would be:

```
headings = ['Opinion', 'Journal', 'Editorial', 'Magazine', 'Evidence-based']
```

Comment: What values should be 1, and what should be 0?

Comment: @nbryans Have edited the question.

Answer (score 10):

If you are able to use Pandas, this functionality is essentially built-in there:

```
import pandas as pd

l = ['Opinion, Journal, Editorial', 'Opinion, Magazine, Evidence-based', 'Evidence-based']
pd.Series(l).str.get_dummies(', ')
```

```
   Editorial  Evidence-based  Journal  Magazine  Opinion
0          1               0        1         0        1
1          0               1        0         1        1
2          0               1        0         0        0
```

---

If you'd like to stick with the `sklearn` ecosystem, you are looking for `MultiLabelBinarizer`, not for `OneHotEncoder`. As the name implies, `OneHotEncoder` only supports one level per sample per category, while your dataset has multiple.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()  # pass sparse_output=True if you'd like
mlb.fit_transform(s.split(', ') for s in l)
```

```
[[1 0 1 0 1]
 [0 1 0 1 1]
 [0 1 0 0 0]]
```

To map the columns back to categorical levels, you can access `mlb.classes_`. For the above example, this gives `['Editorial' 'Evidence-based' 'Journal' 'Magazine' 'Opinion']`.

Comment: Will this work irrespective of the order of the categories?

Comment: @user7347576 yes, if you're asking whether `Opinion, Journal` or `Journal, Opinion` makes a difference, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

One more way:

```
l = ['Opinion, Journal, Editorial', 'Opinion, Magazine, Evidence-based', 'Evidence-based']

# Get list of unique classes
classes = list(set([j for i in l for j in i.split(', ')]))
=> ['Journal', 'Opinion', 'Editorial', 'Evidence-based', 'Magazine']

# Get indices in the matrix
indices = np.array([[k, classes.index(j)] for k, i in enumerate(l) for j in i.split(', ')])
=> array([[0, 1],
          [0, 0],
          [0, 2],
          [1, 1],
          [1, 4],
          [1, 3],
          [2, 3]])

# Generate output
output = np.zeros((len(l), len(classes)), dtype=int)
output[indices[:, 0], indices[:, 1]]=1
=> array([[ 1,  1,  1,  0,  0],
          [ 0,  1,  0,  1,  1],
          [ 0,  0,  0,  1,  0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most efficient method, but probably easy to grasp.
If you don't already have a list of all possible words, you need to create that. In the code below it's called `unique`. The columns of the output matrix `s` will then correspond to those unique words; the rows will be the item from the list.

```
import numpy as np

lis = ['Opinion, Journal, Editorial','Opinion, Magazine, Evidence-based','Evidence-based']

unique=list(set(", ".join(lis).split(", ")))
print unique
# prints ['Opinion', 'Journal', 'Magazine', 'Editorial', 'Evidence-based']

s = np.zeros((len(lis), len(unique)))
for i, item in enumerate(lis):
    for j, notion in enumerate(unique):
        if notion in item:
            s[i,j] = 1

print s
# prints [[ 1.  1.  0.  1.  0.]
#         [ 1.  0.  1.  0.  1.]
#         [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]]
```

Answer (score -1):

Very easy in `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(['a','b','c'])
pd.get_dummies(s)
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  0  0
1  0  1  0
2  0  0  1
```